# WAMP Server not working when I add a directory directive

Tags: httpd.conf, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am attempting to put WSGI (python) on a WAMP server (Apache 2.2.21, Python 2.7, WAMP 2.2a). Unfortunately, when i add just a simple directory directive and restart, Apache won't start. here is the code:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<Directory “C:/wamp/www/python”>
#Options ExecCGI
#AddHandler wsgi-script .py
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If I comment out the directory tags, like this:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

#<Directory “C:/wamp/www/python”>
#Options ExecCGI
#AddHandler wsgi-script .py
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from all
#</Directory>
```

It starts. Why won't this work (it also doesn't work with everything uncommented)? I  followed all of the directions on [this tutorial](http://martinprzybyla.com/2011/02/01/how-to-get-python-working-with-apache-and-wampserver-win-7/). Other than the changes in the code snippets, I have changed nothing in httpd.conf, other than including the file that contains the code snippet. I did that with:

```
Include conf/extra/changes.conf
```

on the very last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write your configs in MS Word or Wordpad; your quotes are broken.

Change:

```
<Directory “C:/wamp/www/python”>
```

to:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/python">
```

There's also a space in your `AddHandler` filename, you'll want to fix that too in order to get the whole thing working.

Comment: hmm... i wrote it in plain old notepad... that fixed it. TY.

Comment: @invisiblebob Oh, it's actually wrong in the tutorial that you linked - that would be the issue, not the text editor that you used.  I guess the author made that mistake, instead!